# Getting error in CodeIgniter DB query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter. I am trying to get table rows by get function by getting below the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/viewBySemester.php
Line Number: 17
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['courses'] = $this->courses_model->Course();
```

**In Model**

```
return $this->db->get('courses');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Carefully read the [CI Database Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/). That's what I did when learning CI.

Comment: Did you actually read the error message?  This has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by changing in your controller, something like this

```
$data['courses'] = $this->courses_model->course()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changes in your model:

```
return $this->db->get('courses')->result();
```

Comment: Mind explaining your answer a bit?  It's unclear how this answers the question.